# Codeigniter Follow System: select all status types

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this follow system that lets you follow certain type of statuses. When you follow someone, it puts your user id into the friends table along with the friend's id. Lastly, it adds in what type of statuses you want to follow. So say a user wants to follow just my statuses and not photos, the type would = 1 for statuses. The statuses table has the type in it too, so this query works just fine for that, but I want it to select all status types if the type is equal to zero, so how would I do that?

```
$this->db->select('statuses.type,statuses.text,statuses.media_url,statuses.user_id,statuses.id,users.name,users.username,users.avatar');
$this->db->from('statuses');
$this->db->join('friends', 'friends.type = statuses.type AND friends.friend_id = statuses.user_id OR friends.user_id = statuses.user_id');
$this->db->join('users', 'users.id = statuses.user_id');
$this->db->where('friends.user_id', $user_id);
$this->db->where('friends.confirmed', 1);
```

friends.type, when equal to 1, would select statuses types = to 1 in the status table. This would work if the type = 2 or 3 for the other types of statuses, like photos or videos. Like I said, I just need a way to select all status types if the friends.type = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this?:

```
$this->db->join('friends', '(friends.type = 0 OR friends.type = statuses.type) AND (friends.friend_id = statuses.user_id OR friends.user_id = statuses.user_id)');
```

Comment: No, because if the type = 0 it needs to select all status types, if the type in statuses.type = 1,2,3,4,5 it should select all no matter what. That also renders an error.

Comment: The intent of the `OR` condition is to skip the processing of `friends.type = statuses.type` when `friends.type = 0` in your join, which would be filtering out statuses by type. Also, I think depending on how you have it set up, CodeIgniter may be choking on the parens.

Comment: but why do I get an error? CI seems to not like the parenthesis.

Comment: if I change to this: 'friends.type = 0 OR friends.type = statuses.type <> friends.friend_id = statuses.user_id OR friends.user_id = statuses.user_id' I get 'Unknown column '0' in 'on clause'

Comment: CI's Active Record is... special. It's treating 0 like it's a column in the join and escaping it when it constructs the query. If the db you're using allows it, trying throwing some quotes around 0. Otherwise, you may have to check out the _protect_identifiers (or some other escaping function) in the DB_driver.

Comment: Or try taking out that part of the join

`$this->db->join('friends', 'friends.friend_id = statuses.user_id OR friends.user_id = statuses.user_id');`
`$this->db->where('(friends.type = 0 OR friends.type = statuses.type)');`

Comment: I don't really know how to do this, I just started using active record.

Comment: I've been using CI for a couple of years now for my job and, I'm sorry to say it because I use it so heavily, but it will need a LOT of work if you want to do something other than a small project. I've all but given up on Active Record and constructed my own wrapper classes around it to help me out.

Comment: So how would I even accomplish this query?

Comment: If you don't want to dig into the guts of the code and my other suggestions aren't working, I would suggest not using active record for the query (as in, build the query and use the query() function instead). I don't know what else there is available. Good luck!

Comment: yes it is, im trying to do it a different way even though doing it in phpmyadmin worked.